SoundGen Spectrogram gridlines
I'm making some spectrograms using the R SoundGen package but am getting a lot of extra grid lines on the image and can't seem to find a way to make them disappear.
spectrogram(dr,
            osc=T,
            col = c(turbo(100)),          
            heights = c(2, 1),  # spectro/osc height ratio
            contrast = .5,  # increase contrast
            brightness = -0.5,
            ylim = c(0, 2),
            overlap=90,
            windowLength = 50,
            noiseReduction=0.5,
            grid = NULL,
            cex.lab = 1, cex.axis = 1,
            smoothTime = 1,
            smoothFreq=0.2,
            wn = "gaussian")


If I replace my col=c(turbo(100) with one of the colorTheme,             colorTheme='heat.colors' or 'seewave', then they disappear. But I'd like to specify my own.
Edit to add: the lines are the window size used in the function, but I'm still not sure why these appear when I specify a colour range and not when I use a predetermined theme

Totally guessing here, but is it possible your specified color range is not enough values (like it needs to be 101 or something?) so it is filling in with grey? Is there a way to look up the size or values of a given colorTheme?
